# Как сделать выбор в слэш команде disnake.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать такой выбор настроек в слэш команде, как у UnbelievaBoat?
[image]

Comment: Вот пример использования `choices`: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/slash-commands.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: спасибо большое!